# How can I add a progress indicator to numpy.loadtxt?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to load very large text CSV files into RAM using numpy [loadtxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html). Is there a way to add a progress indicator to show that the file is being read? My code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt(filename, dtype=np.int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using the ability to add a custom converter to loadtxt. It prints a . to console every million items.

```
    def conv(x:str):
    if b'.' in x: # if the number has a . in it
        v= int(1e6*float(x)) # treat column zero as floating point seconds and convert to int us
    else:
        v= int(x) # otherwise convert the str to int
    conv.event_counter+=1
    if conv.event_counter%1000000==0:
        print('.',end='')
    return v
conv.event_counter=0 # define function static variable after function, put it in function
events = np.loadtxt(events_path, dtype=np.int64,converters=conv)
```

A little experiment showed this function approach was much faster than using a dict of lambda functions, one for each column.

Answer (score 0):

@Tobi's answer didn't work for me, so I had to fix (and simplify) it:

```
def main()
  def conv(x: str):
    conv.event_counter += 1
    if conv.event_counter % 1000000 == 0:
      print('.', end='', flush=True)
    return x

  conv.event_counter = 0
  events = np.loadtxt(..., converters=conv)
```

Please note if `np.loadtxt` is in function, to use this code `conv` function should be inside that function.